# Subir directorio a un subdominio en Firebase

Tags: json, firebase, hosting, subdominio

Buenos días programadores, estoy intentando hacer que un directorio se asocie a un subdominio en Firebase. Por ejemplo tengo este arbol de directorios.

```
├───.firebase  
├───clientes  
├───negocios  
├───node_modules  
├───public  
├───firebaseserc  
├───firebase.json  
├───package.json  
└───package-lock.json
```

Este es el contenido de mi firebase.json

```json
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Por ahora todo lo que se encuentra en public me lo envia a miweb.com pero quisiera que clientes y negocios por ejemplo me lo enviara a negocios.miweb.com y clientes.miweb.com. Tengo los subdominios ya configurados, pero creo que hay que hacer algo en el firebase.json para que cuando haga el deploy se suban los cambios apropiadamente.
Agradezco los comentarios y sugerencias en buena onda, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He contactado hace ya unos meses al soporte y la solución oficial para la generación de subdominios en Firebase es la siguiente.

Cito textual:

> Para que pueda tener contenido diferente en sus dominios personalizados, lo primero que debe hacer es crear un nuevo sitio de alojamiento, eliminar su dominio personalizado del primer sitio y agregarlo al nuevo. ~Adrian Firebase Support

Por lo que he apuntado el subdominio al nuevo hosting de firebase y he hecho un deploy hacia este nuevo hosting.
Esta solución me ha funcionado perfectamente y he logrado segmentar a los usuarios de las aplicaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Primero creas un nuevo sitio en hosting dentro del mismo proyecto el cual te va generar un dominio nombresitiosub.web.app. nuevo.  De ahí te abre su propio panel de administración del sitio, ahi agregar tu subdominio para redirigirlo.

Para subir los files de ese subdominio creas el json firebase.json dentro del directorio agregando la linea de tu nuevo sitio creado. Esta “parte ‘ site": “nombresitiosub”, ’

{
  "hosting": {
    "site": “nombresitiosub”,
    "public": "public",
    ...
  }
}

Y para Finalizar el deploy:

$ firebase deploy --only hosting:nombresitiosub

Nota: Al crear el "$ firebase init" lo realice igual desde ./ para que se genere desde /public